# How can I programmatically open Microsoft.Maui.Controls.WebView DevTools?

Tags: c#, .net, webview, maui

Microsoft **MAUI** uses a **WebView** Control that wraps **Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.CoreWebView2**.

How can I programmatically open the browser DevTools on windows and other supported platforms without causing exceptions on unsupported platforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since opening DevTools is a non-critical operation we can make a simple extension method that tries to find the method for launching dev tools without adding any references to **Microsoft.UI.Xaml**. This way platforms that do not support DevTools will gracefully be ignored.

**Extension:**

```
public static class WebViewExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Opens the DevTools if available.
    /// </summary>
    public static bool TryOpenDevToolsWindow(this WebView webView)
    { //Since this is a non-critical operation, use reflection instead of adding a permanent reference to
      //Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls namespace for CoreWebView2..
        if (webView != null)
        {
            var platfromView = webView.Handler.PlatformView;
            if (platfromView != null)
            {
                var property = platfromView.GetType().GetProperty("CoreWebView2", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
                if (property != null)
                {
                    var coreWebView2 = property.GetValue(platfromView);
                    if (coreWebView2 != null)
                    {
                        var openMethod = coreWebView2.GetType().GetMethod("OpenDevToolsWindow");
                        if (openMethod != null)
                        {
                            dynamic r = openMethod.Invoke(coreWebView2, null);
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
private async void WebView_Navigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is WebView view)
    {
        view.TryOpenDevToolsWindow();
    }
}
```

Hope you find this useful!